# How do i assigned the type of any object to a .NET generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose that I have created a method like this

```
private void Test<t>(t str)
{

}
```

Now from another method i call it

```
private void BtnClick()
{
    string a = "";


    test<Here I Want To assign The Type what ever the type of 'a' is>();
}
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if `a` is a string, you can write:

```
Test<string>(a);
```

And if `a` is an `int`, you can write:

```
Test<int>(a);
```

Pretty obvious. If you don't know the type of `a` upfront, that means that `BtnClick` should be generic, the problem would be moved to `BtnClick`'s caller:

```
private void BtnClick<T>()
{
    T a = ...;


    Test<T>(a);
}
```

C# 2.0 and later offers type inference, so you wouldn't have to specify the type:

```
Test(a);
```

Comment: C# 2.0 has generic type inference - it is *better* in C# 3.0, but it has been there as long as generics.

Answer (score 1):

You simply call the function passing `a` as the parameter. Type inference will determine what T should be for `a`.

```
static void Main()
{
    string temp = "blah";
    Test(temp);
    Console.Read();
}

private static void Test<T>(T input)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).ToString());
}
```

`System.String` would be printed to the console.

**Edit:** But, yes, absent type inference, and when you know what your type your variable is, you can always be explicit with the type. `Test<string>(temp);`

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `a` is always a `string`, so you can simply use either `Test<string>(a)` or `Test(a)`. If, however, you mean that you have a `Type` instance hanging around somewhere, then you get into the area of reflection. Note that this works, but is slow if used in a tight-loop, so make sure that you understand the performance aspect;

```
        object arg = ...;
        MethodInfo method = typeof(YourType)
            .GetMethod("Test", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .MakeGenericMethod(arg.GetType());
        method.Invoke(this, new object[] { arg });
```